# How to separate specific chars from a column of a PySpark DataFrame and form a new column using them?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am extremely new to PySpark and I really struggle a lot to understand how to work with it. I have a case where I have to apply an operation to a PySpark DataFrame which only consists of column1 as in below and return a new dataframe containing **column1, column2 and column3**:

```
column1              column2      column3
'A123'                '123'         'A'
'321B'   --------->   '321'         'B'
'C875'                '875'         'C'
```

The chars to be separated are ['A', 'B', 'C'] and they can either be at the front or at the end of the string in 'column1'. There are one and and only one of them in each string in column1.

Comment: You can solve this using an udf. Two udfs. one will allows you to extract strings. the second will allow you to extract only integers.  https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use an UDF to do this. Or you can use the built-in `regex_extract` function to extract

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
    ('A123',),
    ('321B',),
    ('C875',) ,
      ]


df1Columns = ["column1"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)
df1.show(20, truncate=False)


import re

def findChar(input_string):
    result = "".join(re.findall("[A-C]", input_string))
    return result

findChar_udf = udf(findChar, StringType())

def findNumber(input_string):
    result = "".join(re.findall("[0-9]+", input_string))
    return result

findNumber_udf = udf(findNumber, StringType())

print("Using udf")
df2 = df1.withColumn("column2", findChar_udf("column1")).withColumn("column3", findNumber_udf("column1"))
df2.show(20, truncate=False)

print("Using regex_extract")
df3 = df1.withColumn("column2", regexp_extract("column1", "[A-C]", 0)).withColumn("column3", regexp_extract("column1", "[0-9]+", 0))
df3.show(20, truncate=False)
```

Following is the output:

```
+-------+
|column1|
+-------+
|A123   |
|321B   |
|C875   |
+-------+

Using udf
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|A123   |A      |123    |
|321B   |B      |321    |
|C875   |C      |875    |
+-------+-------+-------+

Using regex_extract
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|A123   |A      |123    |
|321B   |B      |321    |
|C875   |C      |875    |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to separate the two conditions and get the substrings.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select('column1', 

F.when(
    F.col('column1').rlike('^[ABC]'), 
    F.substring(F.col('column1'), 2, 3)
).when(
    F.col('column1').rlike('[ABC]$'),
    F.substring(F.col('column1'), 1, 3)
).alias('column2'),

F.when(
    F.col('column1').rlike('^[ABC]'), 
    F.substring(F.col('column1'), 1, 1)
).when(
    F.col('column1').rlike('[ABC]$'),
    F.substring(F.col('column1'), 4, 1)
).alias('column3')

)
```